# How to format a csv.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, formatting, export, erb

I am trying to create a csv download link for `@products`, by means of a csv.erb template. Does anyone know a proper way to format the template, how to control line breaks etc?

At the moment I have

```
<% @products.each do |product| %><%= product.sku %>, <%= product.title %>, <%= product.description %>, <%= product.weight %>, <%= product.stock %>, <%= product.lowest_price %>, <%= product.product_range %>, <%= product.tags_list %>
<% end %>
```

And here is my complete csv output file. (Note how things change somewhere near the middle)

```
, Sun and Moon Ring, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 1&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A set of two rings. One representing the sun, and one representing the Moon. Can be warn separately or together.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 0.0, 0, 400.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver knot ring, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 1&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Thin sterling silver ring with a center knot.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 0.8, 0, 230.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass heart ring, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 1&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A thin square shaped sterling silver ring with brass heart.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 0.0, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver heart ring, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 1&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Thin square shaped sterling silver ring with silver heart.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 0.0, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Copper heart ring, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 1&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A thin square shaped sterling silver ring with copper heart.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 0.0, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Rose quartz brass ring, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 1&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A brass ring with centered rose quartz stone.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 1.6, 0, 350.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Chrysoprase brass ring, &lt;p&gt;A brass ring with centered Chrysoprase gemstone.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.6, 0, 350.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass knot ring, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 1&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A thin brass ring with a centre knot.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 0.8, 0, 200.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Pod striped brass bangle, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 2&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered pod stiped design.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 9.0, 1, 450.0, bangles, 
, Two tear drop brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered two tear drop.&lt;/p&gt;
, 9.0, 23, 450.0, bangles, 
, Half sun brass bangle, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 2&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered half sun shape.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 12.2, 3, 450.0, bangles, 
, Stripy brass bangle, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 2&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A thin stripy brass bangle with rounded edges.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 8.0, 0, 350.0, bangles, 
, Triangle bracelet, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 3&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A brushed silver flat triangle shape placed in the centre of a thin silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 1.7, 0, 300.0, bracelets, 
, Cutout flattened prism bracelet, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 3&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A brass flattened prism shape placed in the centre of a thin silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 1.7, 0, 280.0, bracelets, 
,  Wave bracelet, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 3&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A brass wave shape placed in the centre of a thin silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 2.4, 0, 280.0, bracelets, 
, Half moon bracelet, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 3&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A brushed silver half sun shape placed in the centre of a thin silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 2.0, 0, 300.0, bracelets, 
, Diamond earrings, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 4&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A pair of brushed sterling silver diamond shaped earrings.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 1.6, 0, 300.0, earrings, 
, Heart earrings, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 4&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A pair of solid sterling silver heart shaped earrings, with a brushed surface.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 9.0, 0, 250.0, earrings, 
, Half domed studs, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 4&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A pair of solid sterling silver half domed 8mm studs, with a brushed surface.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 1.4, 0, 200.0, earrings, 
, Medium ball studs, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 4&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A pair of solid sterling 5mm ball studs, with a brushed surface.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 1.3, 0, 100.0, earrings, 
, Small ball studs, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 4&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A pair of solid sterling 3mm ball studs, with a brushed surface.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 1.0, 0, 80.0, earrings, 
, Wreath earrings, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 4&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A pair of solid sterling wreath shaped earrings, with a brushed surface.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 9.0, 0, 300.0, earrings, 
, Diamond pendant, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 5&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A diamond shaped sterling silver or brass pendant, with a triangle shape cut out, on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 2.3, 0, 320.0, pendants, 
, Tear drop pendant, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 5&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Tear drop design brass pendant on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 3.6, 0, 470.0, pendants, 
, Wreath pendant, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 5&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A brass wreath pendant on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 3.6, 0, 470.0, pendants, test
, Silver disc pendant, &lt;div title=&quot;Page 5&quot;&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;A sterling silver disc, with a small heart shape cut out, on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
, 2.8, 0, 350.0, pendants, 
, Brass hexagon ring, &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver ring with centered brass hexagon.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass disc ring , &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver ring with centered brass disc.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass rope ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin twisted brass ring.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.0, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver rope ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin twisted sterling silver ring.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.0, 0, 280.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Lapis lazulite brass ring, &lt;p&gt;A brass ring with centered lapis&amp;nbsp;lazulite stone.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.0, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Coral brass ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin brass ring with centered coral stone.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Zwei ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin rounded sterling silver band with twisted brass flat band placed on top.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
, 3.0, 0, 350.01, silver and brass rings, test, another
, Heart cut out ring, &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver ring with a rounded disc and heart cut out.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.0, 0, 300.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver pod ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin rounded sterling silver ring, with a centred silver pod shape design.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.0, 0, 400.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass pod ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin rounded sterling silver ring, with a centred brass pod shape design.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.0, 0, 350.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver bar ring, &lt;p&gt;A rounded bar, with stripe designs, on a flat sterling silver band.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 300.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Turquoise brass ring, &lt;p&gt;A brass ring with centered&amp;nbsp;Turquoise stone.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.0, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver hexagon ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin rounded sterling silver ring with centered cut out hexagon shape.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 320.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver circle ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin rounded sterling silver ring with centered cut out circular shape.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 320.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass ball ring, &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver ring with centered small brass ball.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.0, 0, 200.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver flat cap heart ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin sterling silver flat cap ring with a small heart cut out.&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 350.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass oval ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin sterling silver ring with a centered flat brass oval shape.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.6, 0, 260.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Silver oval ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin sterling silver ring with a centered flat silver oval shape.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 300.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass wrap around ring, &lt;p&gt;A thin sterling silver ring with brass wrapped around the centre.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.5, 0, 250.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Brass loop with silver disc pendant, &lt;p&gt;A brass loop, and sterling silver disc, with small heart cut out, on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 3.6, 0, 390.0, pendants, 
, Loop pendant , &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver or brass loop with small heart cut out on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 4.0, 0, 320.0, pendants, 
, Hollow half sun bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered hollow half sun shape.&lt;/p&gt;
, 12.2, 7, 450.0, bangles, 
, Three stripe brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered three stripe brass design.&lt;/p&gt;
, 12.2, 0, 450.0, bangles, 
, Diamond brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered diamond design.&lt;/p&gt;
, 12.2, 3, 450.0, bangles, 
, Tryptic circle brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered tryptic of circles.&lt;/p&gt;
, 12.2, 6, 450.0, bangles, 
, Pod brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered pod shape.&lt;/p&gt;
, 12.2, 10, 450.0, bangles, 
, Stripy ring, &lt;p&gt;Thin rounded sterling silver or brass ring with a striped pattern.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;Please check our info page for more details on ring sizes.&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 1.0, 0, 200.0, silver and brass rings, 
, Three quarter X brass brangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin, flat, brass three quarter bangle with x patterns.&lt;/p&gt;
, 8.6, 0, 350.0, bangles, 
, Tryptic pod brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered tryptic of pod shapes.&lt;/p&gt;
, 8.6, 11, 450.0, bangles, 
, Slot shaped brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered slot shape.&lt;/p&gt;
, 9.7, 7, 450.0, bangles, 
, Letterbox pendant, &lt;p&gt;A brass letterbox shaped design, centered on a sterling silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 3.6, 0, 450.0, pendants, 
, Flattened prism pendant, &lt;p&gt;A brass flattened prism shaped design, centered on a sterling silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.7, 0, 450.0, pendants, 
, Cutout letterbox pendant, &lt;p&gt;A brass cut out letterbox shaped design, centered on a sterling silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.7, 0, 450.0, pendants, 
, Protea print pendant, &lt;p&gt;A hollow brass stylized protea print design, on a sterling silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 3.0, 0, 470.0, pendants, 
, Cutout letterbox bracelet, &lt;p&gt;A brass cut out letterbox shaped design, centered on a sterling silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.8, 0, 280.0, bracelets, 
, Slanted rectangle bracelet, &lt;p&gt;A brass slanted rectangle shape placed in the centre of a thin silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.8, 0, 280.0, bracelets, 
, Cutout heart bracelet, &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver rectangle shape with a small heart cutout, centered on a sterling silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.8, 0, 300.0, bracelets, 
, Silver disc bracelet, &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver disc, with a small heart shape cut out, on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.3, 0, 300.0, bracelets, 
, Three Quarter striped edge brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin, flat, brass three quarter bangle with striped edge patterns.&lt;/p&gt;
, 3.6, 0, 350.0, bangles, 
, Geometric brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered geometric shape.&lt;/p&gt;
, 3.6, 6, 450.0, bangles, 
, Three Quarter edge bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin, flat, brass three quarter with small indentations along the edge.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.8, 0, 350.0, bangles, 
, Three circle brass bangle, &lt;p&gt;A thin flat brass bangle with a centered three circle brass design.&lt;/p&gt;
, 12.2, 9, 450.0, bangles, 
, Silver loop with brass oval pendant, &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver loop, with small cut out heart, and brass oval shaped disc, on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.8, 0, 390.0, pendants, 
, Cutout heart pendant, &lt;p&gt;A sterling silver disc, with a heart shape cut out, on a silver chain.&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.8, 0, 350.0, pendants, 
, richard parker, &lt;p&gt;This trio of rings, an abstract representation of three animals, is inspired by the magical and mysterious story, &lt;em&gt;Life of Pi&lt;/em&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;Which animal delights you the most? The magnificent tiger Richard Parker, with his stripy paws hugging your finger; the slippery flying fish, raining down from the sky, caught in a moment between your fingers; or the bird, a sign of hope and land, perched firmly on your hand.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;The first twenty purchases of this ring, in either gold or silver, will receive an illustration by Cape Town based illustrator, Katrin Coetzer. Katrin has created enchanting, 11cm x 10cm, illustrations inspired by each of the three animals in our Life of Pi range. (Prints are available &lt;span class=&quot;st&quot;&gt;unless stated otherwise.)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.0, 0, 400.0, life of pi, 
, the flying fish, &lt;p&gt;This trio of rings, an abstract representation of three animals, is inspired by the magical and mysterious story, &lt;em&gt;Life of Pi&lt;/em&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;Which animal delights you the most? The magnificent tiger Richard Parker, with his stripy paws hugging your finger; the slippery flying fish, raining down from the sky, caught in a moment between your fingers; or the bird, a sign of hope and land, perched firmly on your hand.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;The first twenty purchases of this ring, in either gold or silver, will receive an illustration by Cape Town based illustrator, Katrin Coetzer. Katrin has created enchanting, 11cm x 10cm, illustrations inspired by each of the three animals in our Life of Pi range. (Prints are available &lt;span class=&quot;st&quot;&gt;unless stated otherwise.)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.1, 0, 400.0, life of pi, 
, the bird, &lt;p&gt;This trio of rings, an abstract representation of three animals, is inspired by the magical and mysterious story,&lt;em&gt; Life of Pi&lt;/em&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;Which animal delights you the most? The magnificent tiger Richard Parker, with his stripy paws hugging your finger; the slippery flying fish, raining down from the sky, caught in a moment between your fingers; or the bird, a sign of hope and land, perched firmly on your hand.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;The first twenty purchases of this ring, in either gold or silver, will receive an illustration by Cape Town based illustrator, Katrin Coetzer. Katrin has created enchanting, 11cm x 10cm, illustrations inspired by each of the three animals in our Life of Pi range. (Prints are available &lt;span class=&quot;st&quot;&gt;unless stated otherwise.)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
, 2.1, 0, 400.0, life of pi, 
, Nipple ring, &lt;p&gt;A very sexy nipple ring&lt;/p&gt;
, 20.0, 0, 0.0, ,
```

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails gem? Makes generating excel files piece of cake!

Comment: Hey I already have the Excel .xls format sorted out, I just need a clean csv as well! than you